# How to predict the winner in a set?

Tags: r, machine-learning

At the moment I am dealing with some kind of supervised regression problem, which differs from the stuff I have found on the internet.

**So here's what the data looks like**. (I am working with R)
I have a list with many data.frames. Each data.frame contains ~10 rows with some columns, where one columns says, if this row is `winner` or not. If one row has `winner==TRUE` depends on the other variables for this row ( mostly there is just one winner, but there can be also two, maybe even three or none winners in each data.frame ), but more on the values other rows in this set have. And I guess this is the point where it differs from other regression problems I have seen so far, because the training set is not one row containing all information needed to make later predictions, but a data.frame.

One **example data.frame** (they do have more columns)

```
      id sub_condition rating rating_count winner
AVLDTQFT           new     90         4469  false
ARUVJVQM           new     98         4751  false
A2MUQS6A           new     98         5306  false
A38QR7HW           new     98        11494   true
A7AAZ62N           new     99         8000  false
A1OS85DC           new     99         2385   true
```

**So what do I want**?
I would like to feed these data.frames to an algorithm, so I can later on, pass new data.frames and get a prediction for every row in the frame, for how I should change one variable, so this row (if all other stay the same) is `winner`.

What algorithms and principles do I need to use to solve this type of problem?